# NHibernate Session Management w/ Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate, orm

Is this really all that I have to do to achieve session per request with Ninject?

```
public class WebModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {            
        Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => MvcApplication.SessionFactory.OpenSession()).InRequestScope();            
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { /* Routing Stuff */ }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStopped()
    {
        SessionFactory.Dispose();
    }

    protected static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory() { /* session factory stuff */ }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new WebModule());
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this? It just seems too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this post](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) I decided not to do it this way. Unless someone speaks up, I'll just do it [the old fashioned way](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/05/do-you-need-a-framework.aspx).

Comment: The cited post is way out of date (and was then too :D). See https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope Having said all of that, there's no shame in manually and explicitly Disposing `ISession`s depending on what you're doing -- Committing and managing your Unit of Work is definitely something to do consciously.